# Processing cpu Limitation

Tags: limit, cpu, processing

I'm making a 2D game with Processing, when I add a light, fps drops to 20~ from 30, if I add one more, it'll drop even more. But processing only uses %15 of cpu no matter what, how can I increase that, so I can see 30 fps?

```
void castLight(int mapNum){
  color c = color(0, 0, 0);
  if(mapNum == 1){
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
      for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        if(improvedLights){
          putShadow = improvedLights();//not working
        } else {
          putShadow = true;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < torchHolder1.size(); i++){
          if(dist(x, y, torchHolderX1.get(i), torchHolderY1.get(i)) <= maxDist){
            if(improvedLights){
              putShadow = improvedLights();
            } else {
              putShadow = false;
            }
          }
        }
        if(putShadow){
          int loc = x+y*width;
          float r,g,b;
          r = red (pixels[loc]);
          g = green (pixels[loc]);
          b = blue (pixels[loc]);
          r -= 100;
          g -= 100;
          b -= 100;
          r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
          g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
          b = constrain(b, 0, 255);
          if(torchAnimCounter % 31 < 16){
            c = color(r, g, b);
        } else {
            c = color(r+10, g+10, b+10);
          }
          pixels[y*width + x] = c;
        }
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < torchHolderX1.size(); i++){
      for(int x = torchHolderX1.get(i) - maxDist; x < torchHolderX1.get(i) + maxDist; x++){
        if(x - maxDist < torchHolderX1.get(i) && x + maxDist > torchHolderX1.get(i)){
          torchCrossX = true;
        } else {
          torchCrossX = false;
        }
        for(int y = torchHolderY1.get(i) - maxDist; y < torchHolderY1.get(i) + maxDist; y++){
          if(y - maxDist < torchHolderY1.get(i) && y + maxDist > torchHolderY1.get(i)){
            torchCrossY = true;
          } else {
            torchCrossY = false;
          }
          float d = dist(x, y, torchHolderX1.get(i), torchHolderY1.get(i));
          if(torchCrossX && torchCrossY){
            if(dist(x, y, torchHolderX1.get(i), torchHolderY1.get(i)) <= maxDist){
              if(x > 0 && x < width && y > 0 && y < height){
                int loc = x+y*width;
                float r,g,b;
                r = red (pixels[loc]);
                g = green (pixels[loc]);
                b = blue (pixels[loc]);
                float adjustBrightness = maxDist-d-100;
                r += adjustBrightness;
                g += adjustBrightness;
                b += adjustBrightness;
                r = constrain(r, 0, 255);
                g = constrain(g, 0, 255);
                b = constrain(b, 0, 255);
                if(torchAnimCounter % 31 < 16){
                  c = color(r, g, b);
                } else {
                  c = color(r+10, g+10, b+10);
                }
                pixels[y*width + x] = c;
              } } } } } } 
  }//and same things goes for the second map
```

Comment: we would appreciate more info about light because 2D geometry does not require lightning. How you set it up or what kind of light are you using? How many objects do you have in sketch? Maybe some snippet of code would be great.

Comment: I'm just adjusting brightness based on distance between light source and pixels, no shadows. I don't have much object in my sketch, at most 5-6 creature object and one player object. I'll try to put some snippet from codes that adjusts the brightness.(Waiting for 8 hours to pass)

Comment: In general, i would guess it to be the amount of nested for loops in your draw() loop that is likely slowing down your program...

Comment: What renderer are you using? Moving to P3D or OPENGL may allow you to harness more of the resources...

Comment: Changing modes didn't help, I tried all.
Big 2 loops are sweeping screen in x and y axis, like I said, torchHolderX1 and Y1 has 1 variable for each, I mean if it enters first 2 loops 393216 times, with other loop it will enter 393216 + 2 inner loop.

Comment: Then you should reduce size of operational space by searching only pixels within maxDist around torch or maybe calculate them. 
Or you could use some cheap trick as transparent yellow circle placed on torch location.

Comment: The main reason for this heavy process is for casting shadow on every object in the area(like logs, platforms and characters). But I'll try to find another way.

Comment: Assuming that 15% is roughly one cpu "core", you would need to utilize threading to utilize more than that.

Comment: Do you mind posting a runnable version so it's easier to test ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in abilities of OPENGL to light a model? It seems you are doing a lot of manual processing of pixel data to adjust brightness, presumably to give realistic shading, etc. but a 3D model placed in a scene with a PointLight (or whatever) will do all of that and it will take full advantage of the GPU.

Comment: I didn't try shading with OPENGL, but when I switch to OPENGL, my pixel art seems horrible.